# Why does the geometric series converge when Harmonic does not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

It's a known thing that the geometric series $ar^{\left(x-1\right)}$ converges, but my question is why? All the proofs I've been able to find online rely on the fact that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $ar \rightarrow 0$, but wouldn't this be true for the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ which is known to diverge?

Comment: for the series to converge, it is necessary but not sufficient that the terms approach $0$

Comment: $ar^{n-1} \to 0$ is clearly not the only reason why $\sum ar^{n-1}$ converges.

Comment: The proof for the geometric series relies on the fact that it can be summed explicitlly.. Do you have a reference for an online proof that only uses convergence to 0 of the terms?

Comment: I'm aware that there's more to a series converging than the terms approaching zero. [This Khan Video](https://youtu.be/b-7kCymoUpg) seems to conclude  that since the terms approach zero, it converges.

Comment: The video starts with the explicit partial sum of n terms though. Then the term $at^{n-1}$ in this formula goes to zero and you have an explicit formula for the infinite sum. This is quite different from the individual terms in the infinite sum going to zero.

Comment: Is there no explict formula for partial sums of $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: No but $1+\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8})+..>1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}...$